# Ember 2.0 How can I make template and route talk to each other?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, jsonp, ember-cli

I am teaching myself Ember-cli and am trying to build a simple application, which fetches results when user searches for a term. I am getting the ajax result just fine, but I am not sure how to "pass" that to the template

This is my hbs code now /app/templates/product-search.hbs:

The search field works just fine.

```
<p>*Is 'xyz' by deafult. </p>
{{input class="form-control" id="search-string" type="text" value=this.search-string placeholder="Search by Product"}}
<button type="button" {{action "searchByProduct" this.search-string}}>Lookup Product</button>

<ul>

    {{#each result as |item|}}
        <li>Product Name: {{item.prodName}}</li>
    {{else}}
            Sorry, nobody is here.
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

This is the route file: /app/routes/product-search.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({  
    actions: {
        searchByProduct:  function(qString) {
            var term = qString || 'xyz';
            var fetchURL = 'http://some-api.com/search?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&limit=10&term='+term;
            var result = Ember.Object.create({

            });
            return $.ajax({
              url: fetchURL,
              dataType: 'jsonp'
            }).then(function (response) {
                result.set('content', response.results);
                result = result.get('content');
                console.log("Search Result In Then Promise of Model: ");
                console.log(result); //I get an array of objects (screenshot included)
                return result; 
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Console o/p:

[image]

and a single object looks like this:

```
0: Object
productId: 471744
productName: "xyz"
productViewUrl: "https://someapi.com/us/product/xyz/id471744?uo=4"
imageUrl30: "http://.../source/30x30bb.jpg"
imageUrl60: "http://.../source/60x60bb.jpg"
imageUrl100: "http://.../source/100x100bb.jpg"
collectionId: 700049951
collectionName: "XYZ Collection"
collectionPrice: 9.99
country: "USA"
currency: "USD"
wrapperType: "track"
......
__proto__: Object
```

So I do see results in my `result` object but I am still not able to display it in my template. Maybe am not looping over the right object? Or do I need to pass something else? I have no idea what am missing. Any help is appreciated, I've been stuck with this for a couple hours now.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You route `model` hook must return the promise.

Breakdown of what's happening in your code:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        var result = [];              // Create an array
        $.ajax({                      // Start an AJAX request...
          success: function(response){
            result.set('content', response.results);
           }
        });                           // ...but discard the promise
        console.log(result);          // log the array (still empty)
        return result;                // return the array (still empty)
    }
});                                   // much later, the AJAX call completes but
                                      // Ember does not care.
```

Ember gets an empty array. As it is not a promise, it assumes it can use it immediately, so it sets it as `model` and renders the template immediately.

Fixing it:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        var term = 'random';
        var fetchURL = 'http://some-api.com/search?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&limit=10&term='+term;
        return $.ajax({
          url: fetchURL,
          dataType: 'jsonp'
        }).then(function (data) {
            return data.results;   // do whatever processing you have to do
        });
    }
});
```

This way, you directly return the promise to Ember. Seeing that, Ember knows it must wait for the promise to resolve. When the AJAX call succeeds, the data is passed to the `then` handler, which returns the actual data to use. In turn, Ember gets that data and sets it for use by the template.

You definitely should read a bit about [promises](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/). (Beware though that jQuery's “promises” are not standard).

By the way, I see you are loading `ember-data`. You should definitely use it instead of `$.ajax` to load resources. That's what it's for, and it does a much better job of streamlining data models into your Ember workflow.

**2)** Unless you override it, the data returned by the `model` hook will be named `model` in the template.

So just replace `results` with `model` in your template and you'll be fine: `{{#each model as |item|}}`

Comment: I tried the way that you suggested, by using then to capture the results and making sure I dont actually lose the data set, but my `data` object is still empty.. `console.log(data)` in the then method returns an Object with empty  `results` array

Comment: In this case, it means something is wrong with what is returned by the server. The `data` object in the then method will be whatever is returned by jQuery. You set the type as `jsonp`, are you sure the server actually returns jsonp and not something else, like regular json?

Comment: so I am getting results now, see update, but still can't render it in my template.

Comment: I see you changed your example, you're now calling the ajax request from an action. It works differently than in a model. In an action, you have to call `this.transitionTo('routename', model)`. Where `routename` is the name of the route and `model` is your results.

Comment: hmm can you be a little more descriptive? I understand that in my case that would translate to this: `this.transitionTo('search-product', result)` but not sure what that replaces or what is wrong in the current code

Comment: Actions ignore their return value. You would pass the $.ajax promise to `this.transitionTo` instead of returning it, so that the transition is initiated immediately, paused while waiting for the ajax call and completed once the data is retrieved.

Comment: hmm even after implementing this.transitionTo, I still cant render/capture at template's end. and now am getting a `Uncaught Error: More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: search-product` error.

Comment: You actually have three options: **1)** handle this in a component (not in the route) if you don't want the url to change when you search, or **2)** you need a **separate route** for initiating the search and displaying the result (`/search/results`), or **3)** you need your search to use query params (`/search?foo=bar&baz=42`). Possibilities #1 and #3 differ a lot from the initial question. You probably should consider choosing one of those approaches and creating a new question.

Comment: I think the best would be to keep it clean and handle this in a component! Thank you so much for all your help. I'll do that now.